# Can I map a key (caps lock) so it does one thing pressed alone, and another when pressed with a second key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remap CapsLock to Escape and Control System Wide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31970/remap-capslock-to-escape-and-control-system-wide)

Just read this [seriously obsessive post about customising keyboards](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/) and while I'm not going to do everything there, there are a couple of ideas I'd like to nick. In particular he has set up the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key so that:

- when pressed and released alone, it is mapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- when pressed and held, and a second key is pressed, it is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

As he says, this is great for vim users. Is that possible in Linux/X?

He also does something similar with the right and left <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. When pressed alone they map to <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> but if another key is pressed they act as you expect <kbd>Shift</kbd> to work.

Comment: The other question of which this was marked as a duplicate doesn't address shift and parenthesis.  Although I guess it's not hard to modify the source of the recommended solution (`xcape`) to do what this question asks.