# Disable CapsLock functionality on short press

Tags: x11, keyboard, capslock

Is there any way to make pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> effective only on long press? for example it effect only when we press and hold it for half a second?

(I'm using ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: probably modification of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111704/64187) will do the trick